# How do you install the FIFA 12 Demo with FIFA 11 also installed?

Tags: windows-7, fifa-12

I just downloaded the *FIFA 12 Demo*, but when I start the `Autorun.exe` I only get a play button, none for installation. If I click it, the *FIFA 11* startup menu comes up.

If I start `EASetup.exe`, it says the game already is installed.

Any way to fix this?

For clarification: I have *FIFA 11* installed and I am looking for a way to get the *FIFA 12 Demo* installed without uninstalling *FIFA 11*.

This seems to be a general issue with the demo, I found a [german article on the web](http://www.onlinewelten.com/games/fifa-12/news/schwerwiegende-fehler-ea-nimmt-pc-demo-offline-107373/) pointing out this issue as well. What I want to know is if there is a workaround to get the demo installed anyway.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Is it possible that Fifa 11 was installed on the system sometime before and was not uninstalled properly?

Comment: Fifa 11 is installed, Win 7 x64

Comment: Has fifa 12 been installed before?

Comment: Fifa 12 is not even released yet. ;) And no, the demo has not been installed before.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about sports games. You could try to uninstall fifa 11 and then install the demo, that might work.

Comment: Probably, but I don't want to uninstall Fifa 11 just to play the demo. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now found a solution in this [news article](http://www.pcgames.de/FIFA-12-PC-236492/News/FIFA-12-Demo-Loesung-fuer-FIFA-11-Deinstallations-Bug-und-Hotfix-fuer-Gamepads-844491/) (german):

If you remove the following registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\1DC6AEF331AE7EC47AE47AA4A4A0B7C5

you are able to install the demo while Fifa 11 stays installed.

You should make a backup though, so that you still can uninstall Fifa 11 properly later.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. You just sort this out while I was really looking for a solution around internet.

Comment: Glad I could help. Wow, the views for this question really went through the roof. :D

Comment: I tried to delete that registry key, and there was an "Error Deleting Values: Unable to delete all specified values." Therefore, I still have the problem with FIFA 12 not starting.

Comment: Maybe your account doesn't have the sufficient rights. Sounds like a problem for [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) though.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to remove the whole registry key just add a suffix to it like

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\1DC6AEF331AE7EC47AE47AA4A4A0B7C5backup

and the demo will install just fine. Afterwards you can remove it so you can properly uninstall fifa 11.